# Spring Boot batch - MultiResourceItemReader : move to next file on error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

In a batch service, I read multiple XML files using a MultiResourceItemReader, which delegate to a StaxEventItemReader.

If an error is raised reading a file (a parsing exception for example), I would like to specify to Spring to start reading the next matching file. Using @OnReadError annotation and/or a SkipPolicy for example.

Currently, when a reading exception is raised, the batch stops.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it ?

EDIT: I see MultiResourceItemReader has a method readNextItem(), but it's private -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using SB for a while, but looking `MultiResourceItemReader` code I suppose you can write your own `ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream` wrapper where you check for a flag setted to move to next file or to perform a standard read using a delegate.
This flag can be stored into execution-context or into your wrapper and should be cleared after a move next.

```
class MoveNextReader<T> implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<T> {
  private ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream delegate;
  private boolean skipThisFile = false;

  public void setSkipThisFile(boolean value) {
    skipThisFile = value;
  }

  public void setResource(Resource resource) {
    skipThisFile = false;
    delegate.setResource(resource);
  }

  public T read() {
    if(skipThisFile) {
      skipThisFile = false;
      // This force MultiResourceItemReader to move to next resource
      return null;
    }
    return delegate.read();
  }
}
```

Use this class as delegate for `MultiResourceItemReader` and in `@OnReadError`inject `MoveNextReader` and set `MoveNextReader.skipThisFile`.

I can't test code from myself but I hope this can be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks ! My concern at the moment is to find a way to force MultiResourceItemReader to move to next resource. Like I said it has a method readNextItem but it's private. I'm feeling I will have to copy and adapt the class to do so. But I'd prefer not...

Comment: With a listener and one class you can isolate skip logic without 'copy&adapt'

Comment: Allright, I didn't get what you had in mind at the first read. 
You propose to put a "fake" delegate between the MultiResourceItemReader and the real delegate that read my files, which return null to stop the reading process and force MultiResourceItemReader to jump to the next resource. I'll try something like that !

Answer (score 1):

Here are my final classes to read multiple XML files and jump to the next file when a read error occurs on one (thanks to Luca's idea).

My custom ItemReader, extended from MultiResourceItemReader :

```
public class MyItemReader extends MultiResourceItemReader<InputElement> {

    private SkippableResourceItemReader<InputElement> reader;

    public MyItemReader() throws IOException {
        super();

        // Resources
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourceResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        this.setResources( resourceResolver.getResources( "classpath:input/inputFile*.xml" ) );

        // Delegate reader
        reader = new SkippableResourceItemReader<InputElement>();
        StaxEventItemReader<InputElement> delegateReader = new StaxEventItemReader<InputElement>();
        delegateReader.setFragmentRootElementName("inputElement");
        Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        unmarshaller.setClassesToBeBound( InputElement.class );
        delegateReader.setUnmarshaller( unmarshaller );
        reader.setDelegate( delegateReader );

        this.setDelegate( reader );
    }

    [...] 

    @OnReadError
    public void onReadError( Exception exception ){
        reader.setSkipResource( true );
    }
}
```

And the ItemReader-in-the-middle used to skip the current resource :

```
public class SkippableResourceItemReader<T> implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<T> {

    private ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<T> delegate;
    private boolean skipResource = false;

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    @Override
    public T read() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException, Exception {
        if( skipResource ){
            skipResource = false;
            return null;
        }
        return delegate.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void setResource( Resource resource ) {
        skipResource = false;
        delegate.setResource( resource );
    }

    @Override
    public void open( ExecutionContext executionContext ) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open( executionContext );
    }

    @Override
    public void update( ExecutionContext executionContext ) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update( executionContext );
    }

    public void setDelegate(ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void setSkipResource( boolean skipResource ) {
        this.skipResource = skipResource;
    }
}
```