# MultiResourceItemReader - Skip entire file if header is invalid

Tags: java, spring-batch

My Spring Batch job reads a list of `csv` files containing two types of headers. I want the reader to skip the entire file if its header does not match one of the two possible header types.

I've taken a look at [Spring Boot batch - MultiResourceItemReader : move to next file on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107103/spring-boot-batch-multiresourceitemreader-move-to-next-file-on-error).
But I don't see how to validate the header tokens to ensure they match up in count and content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by doing the following,

```
public FlatFileItemReader<RawFile> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<RawFile>()
            .skippedLinesCallback(line -> {
                // Verify file header is what we expect
                if (!StringUtils.equals(line, header)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Bad header!", line));
                }
            })
            .name( "myReader" )
            .linesToSkip( 1 )
            .lineMapper( new DefaultLineMapper() {
                {
                    setLineTokenizer( lineTokenizer );
                    setFieldSetMapper( fieldSetMapper );
                }} )
            .build();
}
```

I call the `reader()` method when setting the delegate in my `MultiResourceItemReader`.

**Note** that `header`, `lineTokenizer`, and `fieldSetMapper` are all variables that I set depending on which type of file (and hence which set of headers) my job is expected to read.

Answer (score 0):

Can we do this in XML based configuration ?

Comment: Hey there! I see this is your first answer to a question. When you have a question for the author, it's best to leave a comment on the question and not give an answer. Answers are best when you know of a solution to the  problem. Welcome and thank you!